# How to print character from a specific character to a specific character with multiple instances of the character?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, slice

I want to know if there's any way that we can print text starting from a specific character to a specific character. (*both are not same*)

The conditions:

- There are multiple instances of start character, so i just want the first instances index to be `start index`.
- The start index and end index are not same, for example "0" is start index and "()" is the end index.
- Also there might be multiple instances of the start character.

What have I tried?:

- I have tried string slicing

```
a="ahklanfatga0-gja0-gmgaf9hatn.pdfkaufs"
indexes=[i for i,j in enumerate(a) if j=="-"]
```

but I have a different start character and end character, so this doesn't work.

For example:

```
a3="ahklanfatga0-gja0-gmgaf9hatn.pdfkaufs" # start char="-", end char=".pdf"

expected_output="gja0-gmgaf9hatn.pdf"
```

Comment: there are multiple instances of the "-" character. Do you want to start with the first or the last occurrence ?

Comment: from the first occurrence

Comment: What do you mean by "has a directory on it"?

Comment: i used os.listdir()

Comment: thanks a lot for all your quick response

Comment: and can anyone help me if i want last occurrence

Comment: Are you intentionally removing all new lines in the file? This looks pretty horrific to me, and there's probably a better way if you show what the contents of `files.txt` looks like (don't need the whole thing)..

Comment: So `os.listdir()` is only returning one item (which you somehow turned into a one line text file)?

Comment: @blueteenth, no i am not removing all the lines but i want to read one line at a time and process the code for that line only and the same for the rest of the lines

Comment: @martineau, yes you guessed it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start from the first occurence of `-`, you can use the following:

```
s = "ahklanfatga0-gja0-gmgaf9hatn.pdfkaufs"
#                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

preprefix, suffix, _ = s.partition(".pdf")
*_, prefix = preprefix.split("-", 1)

print(f'{prefix}{suffix}')
# Outputs gja0-gmgaf9hatn.pdf
```

---

If you want to start from the last occurence instead, you can just change the above line

```py
*_, prefix = preprefix.split("-", 1)
```

to

```py
*_, prefix = preprefix.split("-")
```

This modification will output now `gmgaf9hatn.pdf`.

Comment: oh let me try it once

Comment: thanks a lot for a quick response, its working

Comment: and can you help me if i want last occurrence

Comment: I've updated just for you, Faraaz. I hope you benefit from the power of this answer in your life.

Comment: Can you please also provide an explantion to your code, like how it works and mainly why have you used `*_`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to expand on my comment, because this looks wrong. `file.readlines()` returns a `list`, which you then convert to a string, but then split at `,` anyway. If you don't need other lines, why read them in the first place?

Are you sure that `a3` isn't `ahklanfatga0-gja0-gmgaf9hatn.pdf,kaufs`, which is what it would be after running your code and `files.txt` being

```
ahklanfatga0-gja0-gmgaf9hatn.pdf
kaufs
```

which would make a lot more sense.

Even if `files.txt` only contains one line, and that line is

```
ahklanfatga0-gja0-gmgaf9hatn.pdfkaufs
```

it doesn't make sense to cast it to a string first. Instead read the first line, and modify it appropriately.

In your question `left` doesn't contain `".pdf"` at the end, but in @enzo's answer it does, so I'm not too sure what you want. It would help if you showed what the file looks like, and the output you expect, but here's what I would do:

```
with open("files.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        start = line.find("-")  # use .rfind("-") for the last index
        end = line.find(".pdf")
        if start > -1 and end > -1:
            print(line[start+1:end])
```

This would do it for all lines. If just for the first line, you could do:

```
with open("files.txt") as f:
    line = next(f)
    start = line.find("-")  # use .rfind("-") for the last index
    end = line.find(".pdf")
    if start > -1 and end > -1:
        print(line[start+1:end])
```

Comment: Use `start = line.rfind("-")` to get the last occurrence.